# Can you help me with distribution/Skewness

Tags: distributions, normal-distribution, skewness

Can you tell me if the data normal distributed are? It looks a bit strange. I would say it is skewed
[image]

---

[image]
40,80 and so on are sizes of the Apartments in m^2

Comment: The normal distribution, like the perfect partner, can be imagined but is never encountered in real life. This looks roughly normal and roughly symmetric to me, but as so far often the histogram may conceal more than it reveals. What is the variable? Why do people not use informative variable or column names to help themselves and their readers? How big is the sample size?

Comment: Have you thought of using a Q-Q plot?

Comment: Stack Exchange is different from discussion forums because it is a strict question and answer site, so I've converted your "answer" to an [edit] to your question because it is intended to add more information. More information about how to use the site is in the [help].

Comment: When you have a sample size of just 23, you might as well give all of the data (or anonymize the data if it shouldn't be shared).

Comment: You can't assert that something *is* normal but you probably don't need to.